# How can I clip one composable by other

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have 2 composable elements with a transparent background (simple box with border and transparent background and text in it). They can be moved around the screen. But it is necessary that when one crosses the other, the one that is now moving should be clipped with the borders of the other.
That's about the result I expect.[image]

I tried to find a possible solution using clipPath and Region.Op, but I didn't find a way to get the path of the drawn element

Sample code where second element collapses by click under first.

```
enum class State {
    Collapsed,
    Expanded
}

@Composable
fun Main() {
    val cardSize = 100.dp
    var currentState by remember { mutableStateOf(State.Collapsed) }
    val transition = updateTransition(targetState = currentState, label = "expand_transition")
    val animateDpAsState by transition.animateDp(
        targetValueByState = { state ->
            when (state) {
                State.Expanded -> cardSize + 8.dp
                State.Collapsed -> 8.dp
            }
        },
        label = ""
    )

    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .width(cardSize + animateDpAsState)
            .clickable {
                currentState = if (currentState == State.Collapsed) {
                    State.Expanded
                } else {
                    State.Collapsed
                }
            }
    ) {
        Element(i = 1)
        Element(
            modifier = Modifier
                .offset(x = animateDpAsState + 4.dp)
                .scale(0.90f),
            i = 2
        )
    }
}

@Composable
fun Element(modifier: Modifier = Modifier, i: Int) {
    Box(
        modifier = modifier
            .size(100.dp)
            .padding(8.dp)
            .border(2.dp, Color.Black),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ) {
        Text(text = "ITEM $i")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get `Rect` of Composables in parent using `Modifier.onPlaced`.

Setting these `Rect` as Paths and checking difference you get new `Path`. And by clipping with this `Path` you can clip moving Composable.

```
enum class State {
    Collapsed,
    Expanded
}

@Preview
@Composable
fun Main() {
    val cardSize = 100.dp
    var currentState by remember { mutableStateOf(State.Collapsed) }

    val pathStationary = remember {
        Path()
    }


    val pathMoving = remember {
        Path()
    }
    val transition = updateTransition(
        targetState = currentState, label = "expand_transition"
    )
    val animateDpAsState by transition.animateDp(
        targetValueByState = { state ->
            when (state) {
                State.Expanded -> cardSize + 8.dp
                State.Collapsed -> 8.dp
            }
        },
        label = ""
    )

    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .width(cardSize + animateDpAsState)
            .clickable {
                currentState = if (currentState == State.Collapsed) {
                    State.Expanded
                } else {
                    State.Collapsed
                }
            }
    ) {
        Element(
            modifier = Modifier.onPlaced {
                pathStationary.reset()
                pathStationary.addRect(it.boundsInParent())
            },
            i = 1
        )
        Element(
            modifier = Modifier

                .drawWithContent {
                    val diffPath =
                        Path.combine(PathOperation.Difference, path1 = pathMoving, path2 = pathStationary)

                    clipPath(diffPath){
                        this@drawWithContent.drawContent()
                    }
                }
                .offset(x = animateDpAsState + 4.dp)
                .scale(0.90f)
                .onPlaced {
                    pathMoving.reset()
                    pathMoving.addRect(it.boundsInParent())
                }
            ,
            i = 2
        )
    }
}

@Composable
fun Element(modifier: Modifier = Modifier, i: Int) {
    Box(
        modifier = modifier
            .size(100.dp)
            .border(2.dp, Color.Black),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ) {
        Text(text = "ITEM $i")
    }
}
```